# Constructor is calling a function which is using the current class type

Tags: c++, constructor

```
NavCal(int in){ read(in, *this) } //constructor for NavCal class
```

The second parameter of the function `void read(int, &Navcal)` inside the constructor body their is the reference to an `NavCal` typed object.

There is no issues while the definition of the constructor is outside the `NavCal` class and physically below the `read` function. But for the moment I have to define the constructor inside the `NavCal` class. And while forward declare the `read` function above the `NavCal` class, the compiler won't understand what is the `NavCal` class when it seeing the forward declaration.

Q: How can I solve this bad loop while keep the definition of the constructor inside the class?

Please address the code snipe below

```
#include <iostream>

std::istream &read(std::istream&, NavCal&);

struct NavCal {
    NavCal() = default;
    NavCal(std::istream &is)
    {
        read(is, *this);
    }

    int getPr() const { return pr; };

    int pr;
};

// nonmember functions
std::istream &read(std::istream &is, NavCal& navCal_1)
{
    is >> navCal_1.pr;
    return is;
}
```

Comment: @user463035818 Error fixed and code spinet is added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And while forward declare the read function above the NavCal class, the compiler won't understand what is the NavCal class when it seeing the forward declaration.

So forward-declare `NavCal`!

```
struct NavCal;
void read(int, NavCal&);

struct NavCal
{
   NavCal() { read(42, *this); }
};
```

This is really what forward declarations are for. Declaring a function is just business as usual.

---

You're right to say that the other possibility, and one that I would still consider, is to separate declarations from definitions:

```
// NavCal.h
struct NavCal
{
   NavCal();
};

// MyReadingStuff.h
#include "NavCal.h"
void read(int, NavCal&);

// NavCal.cpp
#include "NavCal.h"
NavCal::NavCal()
{
   read(42, *this);
}
```

… but that's not always convenient/logistical/possible.

In fact, even in that last example, I'd probably just forward-declare `NavCal` in `MyReadingStuff.h` to save an unnecessary include (which then propagates!). So it's kind of moot. :)